# Best way to design Domain with constant in grails

Tags: database, grails, grails-orm, domain-object

I have lots of domain classes in my project. Many of them has type column. For example: `User` table has `userType` column, `Book` table has `bookType` column. I often pass these types into GSP `g:select` source by calling `BookType.list()` method. But problem is if GSP contains lots of `g:select` then I have to execute lots of redundant query.

And another problem is when I create a new Domain instance, I have to get these constant types from DB by following way

```
Book book = new Book();
book.bookType = BookType.findByName(BookTypes.COMICS);
```

Here I also have the same problem, I have to execute redundant query. Is there any good design to do all these stuff without executing these redundant queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `types` are not very volitile, I assume that is the case because I can see you defined an `enum` for type. Try using `enum`, totally -- I mean, don't bother with the database table at all to back that up. For example,

```
enum SomeType {

    TYPE1(1, "Type 1"),
    TYPE2(2, "Type 2"),
    TYPE3(3, "Type 3")

    final int id
    final String value

    private SomeType(int id, String value) {
        this.id = id
        this.value = value
    }

    // Might be needed for <g:select> tags, I'm not very sure
    int getKey() { id }

    static SomeType byId(int id) {
        values().find { it.id == id }
    }
}
```

Then, in your domain, do something like,

```
class SomeDomain {

    static constraints = {
        ...
        type nullable: false
        ...
    }

    ...
    SomeType type
}
```

Then, you can simply do something like this,

```
SomeDomain book = new SomeDomain(..., type: SomeType.TYPE1, ...);
```

Comment: How to handle BookType.list() ?

Comment: @EmdadulSawon: The answer is already given, notice `byId(...)` method, I defined up there. You're right, `BookType.values()` is the way to go.